# Guzzle to ryver api

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, guzzle

Hello guys i've been pulling my hair for this problem. I'm accessing an api from ryver to send post chat messages for automated notification. I'm following this doc https://support.ryver.com/chatmessage-api/ and I'm using laravel 5.1 with Guzzle and here's my code if it helps

```
$client = new Client();
        $postData = \GuzzleHttp\json_encode(['JSON Payload' => ['body' => 'test123']]);



        $options = [
            'json' => $postData
        ];

        $request = $client->post('https://somecompany.ryver.com/api/1/odata.svc/workrooms(1099207)/Chat.PostMessage()', $options);
        $request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $request->setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        $request->setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic Base64codehere');

        $response = $request->send();
```

It always returns a [status code] 400, Please help :( Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: What does the response body have?

Comment: I can't send any response @JonStirling because it's throwing an exception .
Client error response
[status code] 400
[reason phrase] Bad Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it :) I just need to stringfy the JSON to make it work and set body the JSON. here's the code.

```
$client = new Client();
        $postData = '{
        "body":"**Update!**\n> ** Test success for ryver integration.",
          "extras": {
            "from": {
              "__descriptor":"Developer",
              "avatarUrl":"https://cdn2.f-cdn.com/ppic/4973381/logo/4389970/developer_avatar.png"
            } 
          }
        }';
        $request = $client->post('https://company.ryver.com/api/1/odata.svc/workrooms(1098712)/Chat.PostMessage()',[
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Basic base64'
        ]);

        $request->setBody($postData);

        $response = $request->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try sending the API request using this params

```
$postData = \GuzzleHttp\json_encode(['body' => 'test123']);

$options = [
    'JSON Payload' => $postData
];
```